# Best way to unifies several arrays into one sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, hashset

The following is taken from a job interview:

> For an array of sorted arrays, write a function that unifies the
>   arrays into one sorted array.

I thought about using an `HashSet<E>`, and add a whole array, for each array, with a single order(I don't know, but it must be a pre-written method for it?!), but I can swear there's a simple solution for that...

Any suggestions ?

Thanks !

Comment: That would be *merge* step of merge sort.

Comment: @RohitJain Can you code example this ? thanks...

Comment: how about trying it out. That's a major hint I've given. Please don't ask out for code around.

Comment: @RohitJain I know and I appreciate that, I know a descend solution will be a merge sort n-1 times for n arrays, but are there structural methods that I can have HashSet as an advantage to shorten a future code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to steal a method from the mergesort algorithm which combines two (can be extended to more) arrays. Here is an example (for merging 2 arrays):

```
private static int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right) {
    int lengthResult = left.length + right.length;
    int[] result = new int[lengthResult];
    int indexL=0, indexR=0, indexResult = 0;

    //while there are elements left in left or right
    while(indexL < left.length || indexR < right.length){

        //BOTH left and right still have elements 
        if(indexL < left.length && indexR < right.length){
            //if the left item is greater than right item
            if(left[indexL] <= right[indexR]){
                result[indexResult] = left[indexL];
                indexL++;
                indexResult++;
            }else{
                result[indexResult] = right[indexR];
                indexR++;
                indexResult++;
            }
        //means only left OR right have elements left
            //see if left has stuff
        }else if(indexL < left.length){
            result[indexResult] = left[indexL];
            indexL++;
            indexResult++;
        }else if(indexR < right.length){
            result[indexResult] = right[indexR];
            indexR++;
            indexResult++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```